# Inconsistent dom event object value in React code, though I don't think the problem is with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, dom-events

I'm having trouble getting consistent data from the click handler passing event. I'm loading rows in a table using the following code, and need the id of the current row when the button is clicked so that I know which record to delete.

```
let rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++){
  let id = documents[i].id;
  rows.push(<tr key={id}>
              <td>{documents[i].name}</td>
              <td><button id={id} onClick={this.toggledeleteConfirmModal}>X</button></td>
            </tr>);
}
```

The click handler looks like this

```
toggledeleteConfirmModal = (e) => { let id = e.target.id; console.log(id); ... };
```

The value of id is either an empty string, or the correct value. Does anybody know what I'm not understanding here, and could you please suggest a fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], including [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The above is quite good, but would be much better with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Thanks T.J. Those are really great tips on how to use this platform. I seem to have sacrificed completeness for minimalism. I understand how to improve for my next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to speculate that your `button` element doesn't really just have `X` in it; instead, you have some elements in it, like this:

```
<button id={id} onClick={this.toggledeleteConfirmModal}>Text <i>here</i></button>
```

If so, the reason is that the [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) on `e` refers to the element that was clicked, not the element on which  you've hooked the event, and if you click the word "here" above, that's the `i` element, not the `button` element.

Use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead. That's the element on which you hooked the event:

```
toggledeleteConfirmModal = (e) => { let id = e.currentTarget.id; console.log(id); ... };
// --------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Outstanding! I did my best (inadvertently) to obscure the problem and you still figured it out. Thank you very much.